# Flex: Find the width of text in a spark label

Tags: apache-flex, size

Suppose I have a (Spark) label.  What is the best way to find the length of the text in it?  I looked at the `myLable.measureText("bla bla")` method but it says:

> To measure text in Spark components, get the measurements of a spark.components.Label or spark.components.RichText

After looking around I cannot find what this is refering to.  I tried `myLabel.measureWidth()` but this does not return anything usefull (it frequently returns zero).

Note: I am explicitly setting the width like this:

```
<s:Lable width="{globalWidthVariable"} .../>
```

If the text overflows I would like to increse the `globalWidthVariable` to the size of the text.

Comment: You could omit the `width` attribute. The `Label` should resize automatically in order to show the complete text.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Seems to me you're going about it the wrong way.  Why not use a container? Maybe let the label resize itself?

Comment: @J_A_X I have multiple labels and I want them to all resize to the size of the largest label (hence why I am setting them to be the size of a variable).  Normally I would just use a component to do this (like a table etc) but each label is inside of an item renderer of a combobox.

Comment: Well, that's going to get dicey because since it's in a combobox, it means that the item renderers will get recycled and there's no way of knowing what's the widest one without rendering *all* labels at the same time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `width` attribute will work as long as you never set the `width` attribute.  (Setting the width attribute turns off auto sizing.)  To avoid setting the width attribute I: read from the width addribute and placed a buffer beside the text box like this:

```
<hbox>
  <label id="myLable" ... />
  <spacer width="{globalWidthVariable - myLabel.width}" />
</hbox>
```

The spacer cannot make the label smaller than `globalWidthVariable` but it can expand it (only functionality I require).